# How to remove the tag cloud from custom taxonomy admin page?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags

When I register the taxonomy I have this which I thought might hide it:

```
'show_tagcloud' => false
```

The default category page does not show a tag cloud so why does my custom taxonomy page, how do I disable it?

[image]

```
register_taxonomy('gmc_region', 'recipe', 
array(
  'labels' => array( 
    'name' => _x( 'Regions', 'taxonomy general name' ), 
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Region', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Regions' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search Regions' ), 
    'all_items' => __( 'All Regions' ), 
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Region' ), 
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Region:' ), 
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Region' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Region' ), 
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Region' ), 
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Region Name' ), 
    'menu_name' => __( 'Regions' ), 
  ),
  'rewrite' => array( 
    'slug' => 'regions',
    'with_front' => false
  ), 
  'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
  'show_ui' => false,
  'show_tagcloud' => false
)
);
```

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Can we see your code that registers your taxonomy please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A bit late but I just learned how to remove the taxonomy cloud. In your taxonomy label definition change this line

```
'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Regions' ),
```

to this

```
'popular_items' => NULL,
```

and the tag cloud will no longer appear